# Pig: Invalid field projection - does not exist in schema - using BagConcat

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm trying to filter by a field in the schema that I've created, but I can't figure out how to write the field name appropriately. Here's the schema description:

B: {datafu.pig.bags.bagconcat_data2_39: {(campaign_id: chararray,date: chararray,time: chararray,keyword: chararray,display_site: chararray,placement: ch
ararray,was_clicked: int,cpc: int)}}

This is the line I'm trying to use:

C = FOREACH B GENERATE was_clicked;

minclick = FILTER C BY was_clicked == 1;

I think the issue is that the field is clubbed within something else, but I don't know how to write it to get the results I'm expecting - can anyone help?

Comment: It’s likely that you’ll need to flatten the bag or use a nested foreach. Could you include the code where you use the BagConcat UDF as this will make it easier to suggest what to do next?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. There was something I missed at the beginning of the script given to us called a "glob" so I didn't even have to do a join. A little embarrassing, but I got there.